# what is loading a javascript code asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I have seen facebook javascript api mentioning that loading the sdk asynchronously

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
```

what is the difference in loading a script using the script tag directly like the following

```
<script src='as.js'></script>
```

and the above shown code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<script>` tag loads the javascript synchronous in a guaranteed order.  The script will load before other things that follow it (other scripts or other elements of the page).

The first option in your code example loads it asynchronously with no predictable order relative to the other things on your page.

Asynchronous loading has the advantage that nothing in the page `waits` for the script to load and the page can render before the script finishes loading.  Asynchronous loading has the disadvantage that you can only know when it's loaded and available for use if you either monitor a load event for that script or if it calls you when it loads and runs or if you poll for some artifact that it makes available when it runs.

Synchronous loading (using `<script>` tags has the advantage that scripts load in a predictable order so you can load library scripts first and then scripts that use those libraries and know that they will be loaded in the desired order without any special coding.  Synchronous loading of a script that occurs before all the body content can significantly slow down the rendering of the content that follows it because the script has to both load and execute before the rest of the page can be loaded and rendered.

Comment: wow... this was a very useful information. dam dam dam... i would like to bang ma head for not thinking about this for a long time. i am just thinking aloud.... anyway... interesting... besides... what makes the process identify that script tag should load sync'ly and a dynamic script tag which is inserted into the head element load async'ly. is it that by giving a function call like that and inserting a dynamic script tag into the head section makes an async call?

Comment: oh... js.async = true; does the magic. i did not know that js code can be called like this similar to ajax but in ajax if the response is a js code then we should use eval. hhhmmm... am i right? and noth script tag and ajax serves for a little different purposes ... . your advice please.

Comment: @JayapalChandran - you're trying to make it a lot more complicated than it is.  If it's a `<script>` tag present in the HTML of the page, then it's loaded synchronously.  If the `<script>` tag is inserted via javascript, then it's load asynchronously.  To add to that, a few browsers support an `async` or `defer` attribute on the script tag that lets you tell the browser that even a `<script>` tag in your HTML should be async.  See [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async) for more info.